# Beginner: Extracting multiple variables when prompted

Tags: javascript, string, object, var

I have the following code:

What I want to do is when I enter my prompt, I want to able to enter multiple variables and receive their outputs. How exactly do I go about doing that.

For example, when I enter lh0, lh1 and lh3, I expect to get back 000110100110010111101

```
var outputRef = document.getElementById('outputArea');
var output = " ";

var areas = prompt("Enter no :  "); 

var areas1 = {

        lh0 : "0001101",
        lh1 : "0011001",
        lh2 : "0010011",
        lh3 : "0111101",
        lh4 : "0100011",
        lh5 : "0110001",
        lh6 : "0101111",
        lh7 : "0111011",
        lh8 : "0110111",
        lh9 : "0001011"


};


if (areas1 [ areas ] !== undefined) 
{
    areas = areas1[areas];

}

output = areas;
outputRef.innerHTML = output;
```

Thanks!

Comment: please add exactly what you want to enter for getting the wanted result. have you considered to use a loop for it?

Comment: What do you mean exactly for "what you want to enter for getting the wanted result." I have stated that using the prompt, I will key in lh0 and so on. I have considered using a loop but I have no idea how to go about it

Comment: well, you could write the first, enter it, then the next, tec, or jusit in one, separated by space or comma, or whatever. so how do you enter the wanted information to a single(?) prompt?

Comment: And Eliza, also just answered here...honestly do you really want that pop up in your face (prompt)? cant you make use of "html select multiple" or just a normal "text box"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#split` to split the string entered by the user, e.g. `lh0, lh1, lh2`, then find the corresponding key in the `areas1` object and add it's value to the `output` string. Finally, display it in the DOM.

```js
var outputRef = document.getElementById('outputArea');
var output = "";

var areas = prompt("Enter no :  ");

var areas1 = {
  lh0: "0001101",
  lh1: "0011001",
  lh2: "0010011",
  lh3: "0111101",
  lh4: "0100011",
  lh5: "0110001",
  lh6: "0101111",
  lh7: "0111011",
  lh8: "0110111",
  lh9: "0001011"
};

areas.split(',').forEach(function(v){
  output += areas1[v.replace(' ', '')];
});

outputRef.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<p id="outputArea"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var outputRef = document.getElementById('outputArea');
var output = " ";

var areas = prompt("Enter no :  "); 

var areas1 = {

        lh0 : "0001101",
        lh1 : "0011001",
        lh2 : "0010011",
        lh3 : "0111101",
        lh4 : "0100011",
        lh5 : "0110001",
        lh6 : "0101111",
        lh7 : "0111011",
        lh8 : "0110111",
        lh9 : "0001011"


};


var results = [];

if (areas) 
{
    areas.split(',').forEach(function(val) {
      results.push(areas1[val]);
    });
}

outputRef.innerHTML = results.join("");
```

```html
<div id="outputArea">
</div>
```